# Смена значений nf_conntrack при запуске Debian 8

Tags: debian, iptables

Столкнулся с проблемой применения параметров для nf_conntrack при запуске Debian 8.1.

Если во время работы применить параметрам

```
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_generic_timeout
```

другие значения, то они сразу применяются.

Если эти значения добавить в sysctl.conf, то при запуске Debian 8.1 эти параметры остаются с дефолтными значениями.

Т.е. при запуске sysctl не меняет их, но если после запуска применить команду sysctl -p, то значения меняются из файла sysctl.conf.

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1):

согласно `man sysctl`, системными конфигурационными файлами для этой программы являются:

```
/run/sysctl.d/*.conf
/etc/sysctl.d/*.conf
/usr/local/lib/sysctl.d/*.conf
/usr/lib/sysctl.d/*.conf
/lib/sysctl.d/*.conf
/etc/sysctl.conf
```

возможно, в каком-то из них данные значения переопределяются.

возможно, какая-нибудь программа/скрипт при запуске системы (после исполнения `/etc/init.d/procps`) переопределяет содержимое перечисленных вами псевдо-файлов.

возможно, в момент исполнения `/etc/init.d/procps` этих псевдо-файлов ещё не существует (как я догадываюсь, они создаются при загрузке какого-то из модулей *nf_conntrack**).

> Как это исправить?

например, поместите команду(-ы), изменяющую перечисленные вами псевдо-файлы, в файл `/etc/rc.local` (выше строки `exit 0`). данный файл интерпретируется в самом конце загрузки.

Comment: Я думал о внесении команд в /etc/rc.local, но это кривой способ. Система чистая, так что врятли какая-то программа переопределяет значения. Конф. файлы пересмотрел, тоже не нашел переопределение. Создается впечатление, что модуль nf_conntrack запускается позже, чем sysctl при загрузки. Но самое странное, что такой баг не пофиксили, так как уже давно используют nat на linux, тем более на debian 8.

Comment: если всё так и обстоит, и модуль, создающий псевдо-файлы, загружается позже запуска `/etc/init.d/procps`, то это, конечно, не баг sysctl, а просто вы требуете от sysctl невозможного.

Comment: @nerik  А почему это баг, в большинстве случаев эти переменные никто не меняет. Вам возможно стоит поставить загрузку iptables раньше установки настроек sysctl что бы модуль прогрузился

Comment: Ну почему же) В офф. документации сказано, что править значения нужно через sysctl. Не думаю что разработчики прям ошиблись.

Comment: *В офф. документации* — в документации чего именно?

Comment: @Mike, как это никто не правит) Когда через сервер проходит более 200 мб трафика, эти значения жизненно важны.

Comment: @alexander barakin, в официальной документации.

Comment: @nerik Мне бы просто в голову не пришло ставить debian на систему через которую проходит 200MBit трафика. Он у меня только не десктопах встречается.

Comment: в официальной документации чего именно? приведите, пожалуйста, ссылку, если затрудняетесь с ответом.

Comment: Ребата, я почему зацепился за sysctl. Дело в том, что я хочу собрать пакет, где эти значения буду править. И не хотелось бы изменять rc.local, чтобы его случайно не испортить).

Comment: @Mike, если у Вас позволяют средства, то Вы несомненно можете купить нормальную железку) А если бюджета нет, то нужно софтовое решение. Давай те не будем в это углубляться. У каждого свои методы решения проблем)

Comment: @alexander barakin, ссылку конкретно не дам) Ибо описание изменения этих параметров описано везде. Значит они были основаны на официальной документации к модулю nf_conntrack. Ну мы уже не в ту степь лезем.

Comment: @nerik Нет, вы меня не так поняли, нормальную железку я не покупаю, на высоконагруженные сервера я ставлю правильно собранную, под конкретное железо gentoo, сборка под железо _действительно_ дает хороший прирост производительности по сравнению с debian, установленный обычными бинарными пакетами. Сейчас посмотрел загрузку debian, sysctl у меня стартует из S13, загрузка модулей из modules.d проходит на S08. Может стоит добавить модули контрак в modules.d

Comment: @nerik, мы как раз приближаемся к цели. попытка изменить псевдо-файлы, которые должен создать **скомпилированный загружаемым, а не в коде linux-а** модуль, это общая «проблема». например: [Tip: Some parameters that can be applied may depend on kernel modules which in turn might not be loaded. For example ...](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/sysctl#Configuration)

Comment: @Mike, тут ещё такое дело, что, возможно, у автора вопроса используется не sysvinit, а systemd. а там своя последовательность и приоритетность загрузки.

Comment: @nerik возможно не modules.d, а просто файл /etc/modules, попробуйте добавить в него `nf_conntrack`, добавление в него вряд ли что то может испортить. просто дописываете в конец файла

Comment: @Mike к сожалению правильно собранную сборку использовать уже не могу, т.к. эта сборка уже стоит на удаленных серверах. Я лишь присылаю обновления, где мне эти параметры и нужно подкрутить, ибо они дефолтные. Так исторически сложилось)

Comment: @Mike попробую добавить, может чего и выйдет)